# Один обработчик события для разных элементов

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Постоянно создаю для каждого элемента свой обработчик события. Надоело. Некрасиво выглядит код. Хочу сделать один обработчик для нескольких элементов. Скажем, есть некое локальное состояние. Пусть оно состоит из двух свойств: input1 и input2. Состояние должно изменяться при срабатывании onChange на элементах input. Пробую решить задачу следующим образом.

```
<input type='text' onChange={this._handleChange.bind(this, 'input1'} />
<input type='text' onChange={this._handleChange.bind(this, 'input2'} />
```

Как видно, есть только один обработчик события на 2 элемента input. Пробую обновить состояние внутри колбэка.

```
_handleChange = (event, id) => {
    this.setState({this.state[id]: event.target.value});
}
```

Круто, не правда ли?) Но, увы, так нельзя. В setState ключ объекта должен задаваться константой, насколько я понял, и не может быть вычислен выражением. Как можно по-другому решить поставленную задачу? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы хотите использовать ключи, которые будут вычислены выражением, используйте [computed properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names).
С ними ваш код будет выглядеть так:

```
_handleChange = (id, event) => {
    this.setState({[id]: event.target.value});
}
```

вот работающий пример: https://jsfiddle.net/sxcm2bdj/2/